# UIWebView caret color with setTintColor?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ios7, caret

I've tried using `setTintColor` on my `UIWebView` instance, `UIView` appearance, and `UIWebView` appearance, but none of them are changing the caret color in a `UIWebview`.

This works fine with native `textarea`s and whatnot, but not in the `UIWebview`. Has anyone been able to change the color of the `UIWebView` caret?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the Tint color for UIWebview will **not** **work** for text *highlighting*. All you can do is *set* the **background color** of that text and then remove it by using *javascript*.
Here's the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28644130/2852281) having the ***Best*** solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the [iOS 7 UI Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/AppearanceCustomization.html):

> Setting the tintColor property by using the appearance proxy APIs is
>   not supported in iOS 7.

Set the web view instance's tintColor directly (that is, not using the appearance API) and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already have `[webview setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];` (`webview` is my instance) in my `viewDidLoad` function and it's still showing the blue caret. Have you been able to do this?

Comment: Sorry, missed that first sentence. Then I guess a web view doesn't let you change the caret and text selection color..